# X,Y uniformly distributed with uniformly distributed parameter

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, density-function

Let $U$ be uniformly distributed on $[0,1]$, therefore dividing the interval in two intervals:  $[0,U]$ and $[U,1]$. Now let $X$ be uniformly distributed on $[0,U]$ and $Y$ be uniformly distributed on $[0,1−U]$.

a) Find the conditional density of $U$ given $Y$.

b) Find the joint density of $X$ and $Y$.

It's quite easy to verify that for a), $f(U|Y) = \frac{-1}{(1-u)ln|1-u|} $. $f(X,Y)$ is less straightforward. I tried writing $$f(x,y) = f(y|x)f(x)$$ where $f(x)=\int f(x|u)f(u)du=\int \frac{1}{u}du =ln|u|.$ However I don't know how to approach $f(y|x)$. What am I missing?

Comment: What's the background to the appearance of [the same question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3608643) twice within half an hour?

Comment: Does $f(x,y)=f(x,y|u)f(u)$? Is this valid?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$f(x,y) = E_U[f(x,y|u)] = \int f(x,y|u) f(u) du$$
Based on the construction of $X$, $Y$:
$$ f(x,y|u) = f(x|u)f(y|u)$$
Where 
$$f(x|u) = \frac{1}{u} I(0\leq x\leq u), \quad f(y|u) = \frac{1}{1-u}I(0\leq y\leq 1-u).$$
Note that the variables $x$ and $y$ appear in the integration bound. 
As an example, to calculate $f(x)$ you may write:
$$f(x) = \int f(x|u) f(u) du  = \int \frac{1}{u} I(x\leq u)I(0\leq u\leq 1) du= \int_{x}^{1} \frac{1}{u} du,$$
where $I(\cdot)$ is the indicator function.

Also note that:
$$U\sim \text{Uniform}(0,1)\Rightarrow f(u) = I(0\leq u\leq 1).$$

Comment: Is $f(x,y)$ going to end up as a function of $x$ and $y$, or as a function of $u$?

Comment: A function of $x$ and $y$. Parameter $u$ should be dropped after integration.

Comment: I don't understand - $f(x|u)$ and $f(y|u)$ are both functions of u, not x and y correct? Where would the x and y come in the integration?

Comment: They appear in the integration bound. I've added an example for you.

Comment: X and Y are not independent, so how should finding $f(x)$ help us find $f(x,y)$?

Comment: This was an example to show the integration procedure, how $x$ appears in the integration bound and $u$ is dropped after integration.