# Independence of two random variables given both are conditionally dependent on third random variable.

Tags: random-variables, conditional-probability, independence, uniform-distribution

If X and Y are both continuous random variables that are conditionally dependent on a third random variable. Are X and Y independent?

The context for this question is part (b) of this question: [Uniform random variables and conditional distributions.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3608643/uniform-random-variables-and-conditional-distributions)

Comment: The only condition given is that $X$ and $Y$ are "conditionally dependent on a third random variable."  What does that mean, precisely? Even though you have not specified the precise meaning, I suspect that most examples of $X$ and $Y$ that you create would satisfy that condition.  What have you tried? What leads you to suspect that independence holds? I do not see anything in the assumptions that remotely suggests independence. It is almost like asking "I have two random variables $X$ and $Y$, are they independent?"

Comment: I guess what I meant was that $X$ and $Y$ are both functions of some other random variable, and I was wondering if this immediately rules out independence between $X$ and $Y$. The link in the question provides all the context I think.

Comment: Let $A, B$ be i.i.d. Gaussian $N(0,1)$.  Define $X=A+B$ and $Y=A-B$.  Then $(X,Y)$ is jointly Gaussian and $X$ and $Y$ are uncorrelated (just compute $E[XY]$)  thus $X$ and $Y$ are independent.

Comment: Other example: Let $U$ be uniformly distributed over $[0,1)$.  Then $U = 0.U_1U_2U_3...=\sum_{i=1}^{\infty} U_i {10}^{-i}$ where $\{U_i\}_{i=1}^{\infty}$ are i.i.d. integers that form the unique decimal expansion of $U$ (with no infinite tail of 9s), and each $U_i$ is uniform over $\{0, 1, ..., 9\}$. Define $X=0.U_1U_3U_5...$ and $Y=0.U_2U_4U_6...$.  Then $X$ and $Y$ are pure functions of $U$ but $X$ and $Y$ are independent and uniformly distributed over $[0,1]$.

Comment: Ok, your second example is a good counterexample. Thank you, but for the first example, is it not the case that uncorrelation does not imply independence?

Comment: @Eloin : For random variables $(X,Y)$ with a jointly Gaussian distribution, uncorrelated implies independence.